# Jump to cell address mentioned in other cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

A1 shows address of last cell un a column (e.g. A572 or A577). Every time address will change if adding new row (there can be blank rows in between of rows with data).
I need a link in B1 to click and jump on cell with address shown in A1. I know that can do F5 and type Address in a Go To bar. Just want to eliminate extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

If every cell in Column A (or any other column) has data in it (i.e., no blanks) up to the place you want to go at the bottom of the column, go to any cell in that column and then use the shortcut combination `[Ctrl][down arrow]` to get to the bottom quickly.